# JaspeReports Table Row Print Error

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

The objective of my study is to print a table that I have on SQL Server, the data connecting is done, the interface and the printing are done too.

The problem occurs when I print the PDf of the report because I want to print a number of rows per page but it only prints me one row of the table per page, so if my table has 205 rows, it prints 205 pages, haha, kinda weird.

This is my first time using JasperReports. Here is my jrxml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="listadoCensosDiarios" language="groovy" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="2400" pageHeight="1000" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="2360" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d8233986-9ca6-4eb9-852a-0c0bf896d505">
<parameter name="ruta" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CodigoCama" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Documento" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Nombre" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Edad" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Empresa" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Especialista" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Diagnostico" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="FechaIngreso" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Dias" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Dieta" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Observaciones" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Registrado" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="FechaRegistro" class="java.lang.String"/>
<variable name="totalPaginas" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page" incrementType="Report" calculation="Count"/>
<title>
    <band height="58" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="df0fa9dd-b7f1-4800-b1bf-f40de1bc7263" x="64" y="1" width="1801" height="50" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f773ff3c-e683-41f4-8f16-7d8c66d54562" mode="Opaque" x="64" y="2" width="1801" height="48" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="20" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[CENSO DIARIO]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="07b7d0a3-0b20-4649-a1b2-0045ca40372e" x="1" y="1" width="63" height="50" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="e076ba71-8906-4238-a19d-f75077425de6" x="1865" y="1" width="134" height="50" backcolor="#E2DEDE"/>
        </rectangle>
        <image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
            <reportElement uuid="e0c8b5d2-3f68-4895-adea-e98d58a2ea3e" x="1" y="2" width="63" height="47"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ruta}+"//img//LOGO1.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
            <reportElement uuid="ce929fc5-57d6-4e20-b30c-9893f34edf61" x="1901" y="3" width="58" height="46"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ruta}+"//img//100calidad.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="b28a6cd6-7bb8-4332-a443-795537750291" x="0" y="8" width="1629" height="16" backcolor="#D3ECC7"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="da28e036-684a-4921-a42a-4afab1ff613a" x="1629" y="8" width="370" height="16" backcolor="#D3ECC7"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="4ec9e82c-884b-49ea-9d84-41ef79374f2d" mode="Opaque" x="1632" y="10" width="360" height="14" backcolor="#D3ECC7"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Información del Empleado]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="0ed0631b-b8b3-4544-984a-6a8b152405a4" x="145" y="1" width="169" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="5d9afa11-5f66-4c24-a689-790b6bbbfee8" x="0" y="1" width="52" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="d3cbfe71-89c2-40f4-83be-c388d60d1f57" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="39" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Cama]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="6e7ec76b-c44c-4ae1-8b14-868e9f596876" x="314" y="1" width="35" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="afc00f8f-d646-48be-b883-11beb5e4e5b3" x="318" y="1" width="25" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Edad]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="065d81fe-b21e-4982-9843-c874f499a969" x="349" y="1" width="150" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="1215c9ac-9bc5-428d-9456-4c9c0ce81129" x="351" y="1" width="145" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Empresa]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="9066f537-b0d4-4a43-b544-14704b4fc207" x="499" y="1" width="150" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="6ba919d0-8dc8-421e-890d-4d9e9bcdf639" x="501" y="1" width="146" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Especialista]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="efeb1184-587c-43ce-bca3-3e6b25f10ea6" x="649" y="1" width="206" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="bc197cfe-a855-4da3-b25e-2d602e16e5c5" x="670" y="1" width="164" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Diagnostico]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="b9dadc2e-8f0d-481d-a82d-f6f47263ef18" x="855" y="1" width="209" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="7c51754f-552c-445e-b7f4-668375f96f3b" x="868" y="1" width="183" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Fecha Ingreso Paciente]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="efe37924-5b8b-46bb-b7ab-c35ec15f16f7" x="1173" y="1" width="156" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="4360b926-3429-4bcf-bf76-28c6ed3af80f" x="1219" y="1" width="65" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Dieta]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="53b0b7be-341c-4d88-9d06-e9ce66f2ba38" x="1329" y="1" width="300" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="739a0a28-415c-4f19-97e7-0eb4d1967f0c" x="1346" y="1" width="269" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Observaciones]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="5c0eb8ea-abbb-430f-8faf-bdc507ccdc43" x="1064" y="1" width="109" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f620ed1e-a0a1-448f-a9cd-13b0824dda53" x="1064" y="1" width="98" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Dias Estancia]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="f0ac1173-7313-46cb-bf0c-072abc746810" x="1629" y="1" width="250" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f0650ba4-1a18-4ff8-b514-928fad9c0e47" x="1629" y="1" width="250" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Registrado Por]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="ea2a4a77-fe25-4b62-8730-b04158cc4f43" x="1879" y="1" width="120" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="051cd84a-f45a-43ae-8e50-476a1723acdd" x="1879" y="1" width="120" height="22"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Fecha Registro]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="146c7aa0-b3cd-496d-a9c7-49b74c37bd64" x="52" y="1" width="93" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f657cfd7-da85-4e30-86ec-720183dbd38b" mode="Transparent" x="52" y="1" width="93" height="22" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Documento]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="64287559-c995-45ba-b97f-dbfbecf62eab" mode="Transparent" x="145" y="2" width="169" height="21" backcolor="#E0E0E0"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nombre(s) y Apellidos]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="626" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="ce513dc9-595a-4018-9b60-4184a87400cf" x="52" y="0" width="93" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="633a32fe-76d0-478c-a2e8-ef73630b698d" x="0" y="0" width="52" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="d1b97bd4-4e00-4aae-a0eb-d9532314933f" x="3" y="0" width="46" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CodigoCama}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="58f022c4-755c-4341-9de7-152dbb01092b" x="145" y="0" width="169" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="9236e426-7562-40b9-8c87-02a31d29dacf" x="314" y="0" width="35" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="d77071b7-c1cc-40e8-ab57-92ad08278390" x="316" y="0" width="29" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Edad}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="76fa21b9-c41d-46bc-8c50-dee329b8c61c" x="349" y="0" width="150" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="81c4e8ba-6de5-471d-b8ca-3e9984105a99" x="354" y="0" width="140" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Empresa}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="836b0a1d-4268-4668-a63e-4df1b4834662" x="499" y="0" width="150" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="e0ee8d88-5ef1-4e7e-b534-c5cef786c942" x="505" y="0" width="140" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Especialista}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="49535787-c02d-4d34-9b83-ed192e0fb086" x="855" y="0" width="209" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="0a4641d9-76f8-4081-ba53-7d68e9934176" x="865" y="0" width="190" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FechaIngreso}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="e4187b85-1c21-4041-8e0e-2c1a6f02cb72" x="1173" y="0" width="156" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="7883fd8a-e3f2-4930-8ec0-37fdb76f4fa4" x="1184" y="0" width="132" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Dieta}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="1a80ef21-1caa-46c2-a1ff-69a810997625" x="1329" y="0" width="300" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="cb697e3d-c8e0-4c98-a588-1eb92008d1f5" x="1345" y="0" width="269" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Observaciones}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="6e960357-27ac-4411-b0ab-1dc6c2bc101b" x="1064" y="0" width="109" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="3eca5ca2-a90b-4c1c-96d4-2ff47b699044" x="1879" y="0" width="120" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="548dcabc-6708-4a4b-902a-7fd7cc30f26c" x="1897" y="0" width="93" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FechaRegistro}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="2cc8851f-d3b4-44cf-a97c-4ad7544765b5" x="59" y="0" width="79" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Documento}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="641978c2-69fc-45f3-a96c-25a53aa138b5" x="1629" y="0" width="250" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="66b12f81-615c-4bb7-8c18-3ce2f0e877d6" x="1635" y="0" width="236" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Registrado}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="0a4641d9-76f8-4081-ba53-7d68e9934176" x="1069" y="1" width="98" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Dias}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="8e458e73-d0fb-4707-b4b8-dd34642725af" x="151" y="1" width="155" height="59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Nombre}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="e021e007-7a56-4ebe-a617-ab39f21dbb32" x="649" y="0" width="206" height="59"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="61d0b9e9-f314-44a3-8aa4-ead1d3e726b6" x="659" y="0" width="185" height="58"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Diagnostico}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="140" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

I tried with a page break but I got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your detail band is too tall.  Set its height to match the tallest element in the band, that is 59 pixels.

Comment: Oh i see, i gonna try your solution, thank you very much

Comment: I tried but all the elements of the report gives me warnings about their position, i set all to 58

Comment: Set the detail band height to 60 then.

Comment: i did the adjustments but i got the same error, it print a row of the table per page i still get 205 pages, oh God... Anyway thanks for your help, if you have any suggestions i am open to them.

Comment: I tried with other values like 65, 70 and it works, i don't know why but it is working for my particular case, thanks for all your support mister dada67 :D

Comment: @Gutierrez: if this is the answer, please accept it by clicking the tick symbol to the left, so that it turns green. This is how we mark questions as resolved on _Stack Overflow_.

Comment: Ok i got it, sorry i didn't get well how i must mark a question as solved.